# Postgres equivalent of MySQL's SET?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to migrate to Postgres from MySQL and have run into a little bit of a problem. I have a form where the user fills out about 40 fields, and these values are inserted into the database. With MySQL I'm used to doing it like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name SET name="John Smith", email="jsmith@gmail.com", website="jsmith.org";
```

I'm also using the `mysql` module with nodejs, and this is what my code currently looks like:

```
var data = {
  name: req.body.name,
  email: req.body.email,
  website: req.body.website,
  ...
  ...
}

var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO table_name SET ?', data)
```

Since `SET` isn't valid SQL, if I wanted to use Postgres, the query would look like this using the `pg` module:

```
client.query('INSERT INTO table_name (name, email, website) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)', req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.website)
```

This would turn out to be very tedious considering that I have almost 40 fields.

Is there any better way to do this or am I stuck with having to write the query manually?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry to say, but that syntax is specific to MySQL. You can write your own wrapper, but I think it will take more time than to rewrite once all of your queries.

Comment: If `req.body` has only relevant own properties, you could use `Object.keys` to both build the `( column_name [ , ... ] )` list and generate a `VALUES ($1, ...)` expression according to length of keys. Then form the list of arguments using that list of keys again and apply. But writing the queries out manually on the other hand has the benefit of not blowing up, if some random key pops in to your `req.body` at some point.

Comment: @IljaEverilä But there should be a list of columns somewhere (most likely from the ORM) so you can start with that list, remove the usual suspects (`id`, timestamps, ...), and be left with a column whitelist to filter `req.body`. A temporary solution but a reasonable bridge to support the migration.

Comment: @muistooshort indeed a whitelist of column names to use from the `req.body` would be even better. It also seems that the original `data` object is already whitelisted, so that could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve when using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), and here's the complete code:

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')();
var db = pgp(/*connection details*/);

app.get('/get', (req, res)=> {
    var insert = pgp.helpers.insert(req.body, null, {table: 'table_name'});
    db.none(insert)
        .then(()=> {
            // success
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            // error
        });
});
```

API: [helpers.insert](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.insert), [none](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.none)

Method [helpers.insert](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.insert) can generate a complete `INSERT` statement for you, properly formatted.

Not only it is the simplest approach, but it is also the most flexible, as you won't need to change anything to start generating multi-insert statements, i.e. if the first parameter for `insert` method is an array of objects, you will get your multi-insert query.

---

And if you want only specific properties from the request, then the best way is to specify them separately, as a [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) outside of requests (to be reusable, for best performance):

```
var cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['name', 'email', 'website'], {table: 'table_name'});

app.get('/get', (req, res)=> {
    var insert = pgp.helpers.insert(req.body, cs);
    db.none(insert)
        .then(()=> {
            // success
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            // error
        });
});
```

#### Example of returning an array of new id-s

**without conversion**

```
app.get('/get', (req, res)=> {
    var insert = pgp.helpers.insert(req.body, cs) + 'RETURNING id';
    db.many(insert)
        .then(data=> {
            // success
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            // error
        });
});
```

**with conversion**

```
app.get('/get', (req, res)=> {
    var insert = pgp.helpers.insert(req.body, cs) + 'RETURNING id';
    db.map(insert, [], a=>a.id)
        .then(ids=> {
            // ids = array of id-s
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            // error
        });
});
```

Comment: How would I do the opposite of `ColumnSet`? I have a field that I would like to ignore from the query (a honeypot), instead of having to write out all the ones that I DO want in the query.

Comment: Never mind... I'll just use `delete data.honeypot` after I'm done using it so it doesn't get inserted.

Comment: @ipgof At present, `ColumnSet` does not support automatic negation, only inclusion. It can, however, accept explicit columns to be skipped, using `?` in front of the name or by setting property `cnd` - see the API.

Comment: Just one quick question, let's say I wanted to do the insert query you demonstrated above, but also returning an `id`, as you show [here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#insert-with-result) in the documentation. How would I do that?

Comment: @ipgof I have added examples for that.

Answer (score 4):

Since you already have an object containing the relevant data

```
var data = {
  name: req.body.name,
  email: req.body.email,
  website: req.body.website,
  ...
  ...
}
```

you could write a query function that wraps the [`pg`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/) client's [`query`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#parameterized-queries) method and adds object-as-values support:

```
function insert(client, table, values) {
    const keys = Object.keys(values),
          // IMPORTANT: escape column identifiers. If `values` should come
          // from an uncontrolled source, naive concatenation would allow
          // SQL injection.
          columns = keys.map(k => client.escapeIdentifier(k)).join(', '),
          placeholders = keys.map((k, i) => '$' + (i + 1)).join(', ');

    return client.query(`INSERT INTO ${client.escapeIdentifier(table)} 
                         (${columns}) VALUES (${placeholders})`,
                        // According to docs `query` accepts an array of
                        // values, not values as positional arguments.
                        // If this is not true for your version, use the
                        // spread syntax (...args) to apply values.
                        keys.map(k => values[k]));
}

...

insert(client, 'table_name', data);
```

Alternatively you probably could rewrite your queries with [`sql-template-strings`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-template-strings), which seems rather nice.

Comment: Thanks for including the `escapeIdentifier` calls. [String interpolation with backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) might be cleaner than all those `+`s if you're assuming ES6+ but that's just nit picking :)

Comment: @muistooshort very true and worth the edit. I still keep forgetting about that, even though it is such a powerful addition to the language.